# Finding hWnd of disabled/hidden [controls]

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm making a program to detect windows/controls of where the mouse points over (very similar to spy++) however I've run into a problem:

originally I've been using WindowFromPoint to find the hWnd's of controls, but have found that disabled/hidden windows do not show.  Every site says to use ChildWindowFromPoint (or a similar winapi) however these do not find controls inside windows.

So...

Is there any winapi that finds windows/controls to the same level of WindowFromPoint while still finding disabled and hidden windows?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for [MS Spy++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowfinder.aspx)

Comment: MS Spy++ uses WindowFromPoint to get window data, so it is still unable to get disabled/hidden windows (i found something about the actual Spy++ and they talked about doing a system-wide window hook, but i don't feel that's necessary for just finding the hWnd)

Answer (score 3):

ChildWindowFromPointEx with CWP_ALL (or CWP_SKIPTRANSPARENT if you want to skip transparent windows) in a loop until it returns NULL, I guess, if you are only looking for windows.

There is no universal definitions for controls as Aussay Marshal pointed out, the controls in Internet Explorer are not windowed, and have nothing to do with controls in other frameworks like WPF or Java Foundation Classes.

If you are writing something like Spy++, check [Spy++ Internals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/01/16/spy-internals.aspx). If you need to automate other programs, check [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486375%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 - rolling your own WindowFromPoint is likely the way to go here; either using one of the other ChildWindowFromPoint APIs, or as a last resort, you can always enumerate the child windows yourself and use your own filtering policy. Note that group boxes can be tricky, since clicks 'go through' them to siblings that they are otherwise on top of; if you care about that, then you may need to roll your own.

Comment: seems like hooks are the way to go, with WindowFromPoint, in programs, buttons/labels/checkboxes etc would show up when you hover over them (except when disabled), in childwindowfrompointex they do not. +1 for good answer tho

Comment: Curious, how do you intend to use a hook here? Hooks are tempting to use, but usually end up being the wrong answer. One thing to be aware of is that in-process hooks - like CALLWNDPROC - don't work across 32-bit/64-bit bounaries; so if your app is 32-bit, it won't work on the shell or other apps on a 64-bit version of windows - and vice versa.

Comment: (Also, if you're planning on using hooks to listen for mouse move or SETCURSOR or HITTEST messages, keep in mind that hidden windows don't get any of these in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

That works for me in C++ :

```
HWND ChildFromPoint_recurse(HWND inHWND, POINT inPOINT)
{
    HWND lHWND = ChildWindowFromPointEx(inHWND,inPOINT,CWP_ALL);
    if (lHWND == 0) return inHWND;

    if (lHWND != inHWND)
    {
        POINT lPOINT = inPOINT;
        if (!ClientToScreen(inHWND,&lPOINT)) return lHWND;
        if (!ScreenToClient(lHWND,&lPOINT)) return lHWND;

        HWND lHWNDrecurse = ChildFromPoint_recurse(lHWND,lPOINT);
        if (lHWNDrecurse) lHWND = lHWNDrecurse;
    }

    return lHWND;
}
```

Comment: It still didn't grab to the level I wanted to, I eventually iterated through with EnumChildWindows, went through the z-order of each window, and got what I needed from there.  Another thing to note, some windows handle control creation without the windows API, which means they wouldn't be registered for any API function to pull a handle

Answer (score 0):

If you really want hidden windows, your only real option is to walk the HWND tree yourself; all the ...FromPoint skip these outright. (Note that hidden windows could have locations that end up blocking you from getting at the visible windows 'underneath' them - so you may want to think about whether you really want to get at hidden windows in all cases, or only as a fallback if there's no other best-fit visible window at a point.)

Use GetDesktopWindow() to start at the root, and descend appropriately; go through each child, see if the point is in it, and if so, traverse down that branch and ignore the other siblings.

To determine children of a HWND, you can use either EnumWindows, or use GetWindow() - but note that GetWindow can give you inconsistent results if the windows change zorder while you're enumerating them.

It's then up to you to figure out how to filter out hwnds; if you only want visible windows, then skip the ones that don't have the WS_VISIBLE bit set.

Checking for 'point is in this HWND' is trickier: checking for point in window rect is the first test; but you may also have to test that it doesn't respond HT_TRANSPARENT to WS_EX_TRANSPARENT - this is what groupboxes use to allow clicks to 'go through' to their siblings that they appear to contain. (You might also need to take shaped windows into account - those use SetWindowRgn to give them an irregular shape; they're somewhat rare these days now that layered windows to the same job.)

--

As an aside, if you don't care about invisible windows, then consider using one the the accessibility APIs: they already do similar work to this. Use AutomationElement.FromPoint and you can get the UI element "at that point". This is great if you really care about UI rather than HWNDs specifically; it will return an object representing an item within a listbox rather than the whole listbox HWND, which the HWND-centric approach will get you - but it won't help you with hidden windows.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can't. you can't get what windows class tje textbox in your web browser belongs to.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question i asked?
i'm not trying to get window classes, i'm trying to get window pointers/handles (next time use a comment if it's not an answer to the question)

Comment: Ohhhh, you are right, sorry I just don't know about windows much. I won't go if there is no class.